# Cannot load report in sharepoint classic page

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, sharepoint-online

Im trying to display a report made in Power BI inside our sharepoint classic page.

The code I am currently using is `<iframe width="800" height="600" src=https://app.powerbi.com/.............."/></iframe>`

But this just displays a flashing Power BI logo.

Any ideas on how to embed a report into a sharepoint classic page would be appricitaed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic pages do not support Power BI embedding. You could embed a PowerBI app instead or upgrade to a modern page